# expose container port in user define bridge network

Tags: docker, nginx

I am creating a nginx container from dockerfile as shown below.

I have performed following sequence of steps.

1. *Dockerfile* content

```
FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

2. Build docker image from *Dockerfile*

`docker build -t mynginx`

3. create user defined "bridge" network "my-bridge"

`docker network create  my-bridge`

4. create nginx container in "my-bridge" network and exposed port 80 of nginx to 
   8084 port of host

`docker run -itd --network my-bridge --name mynginxcontainer -p 8084:80  mynginx /bin/bash`

5. when i try to access container using host port then nginx is not accesible

`http://Public_IP_OF_EC2:8084`

So the question is why am I not able to access *nginx* using host's port?

Comment: Because in your `docker run` command, you're running a shell instead of nginx.  Remove `/bin/bash` from the end.

Comment: Other canonical things to check are AWS security groups, the EC2 host firewall (iptables) settings, and that your nginx configuration is actually listening on port 80.  But none of this will matter if the server isn't actually running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All steps looks good except `docker run`

you are providing `/bin/bash` as entrypoint which overwrites existing `CMD` for nginx.

Kindly start without `/bin/bash` should be working **or** provide valid entrypoint which start nginx service inside container.

Comment: How do you check the default CMD of nginx ?